# Getting CSRF Token from Login Page when it is not provided in the Cookies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, csrf

So, I understand sometimes you can get a CSRF token from a cookie. Using the Python Requests module, I could do `client.get` and something like `value = client.cookies['csrftoken']`.

What other ways are there for a login page to generate a CSRF token? Is it possible for the browser itself to do it?

How would I get that token?

Might I use selenium to make sure whatever processes that generate the token?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem? I'm trying to do the exact same thing...